# select cases and record structures:dont know how to display the string on the grid from the returns of the select cases

Tags: vb.net

My problem is that select cases and record structures: Don't know how to display the string on the grid from the returns of the select cases

Here is my code for analysis:

```
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Option Strict On

Public Class Form1
    Private total As Integer
    Private Structure NGO
        Public name As String
        Public leader As String
        Public supporters As Integer
        Public hours As Integer
        Public average As Double
        Public ratio As Double
        Public status As String
        Public numgroups As Integer          
    End Structure
    Private groups As NGO

    Private Sub display(ByVal r As Integer, ByVal c As Integer, ByVal t As String)
        grd.Row = r
        grd.Col = c
        grd.Text = t
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        display(0, 2, "Leader")
        display(0, 3, "Supporters")
        display(0, 1, "Hours spent")
        display(0, 4, " Level")
        groups.numgroups = CInt(InputBox("input number of groups"))

        grd.Rows = groups.numgroups + 2
        display(groups.numgroups + 1, 0, "Total")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim x As Integer
        For x = 1 To groups.numgroups
            groups.name = CStr(InputBox("name of group no. " & CStr(x)))
            display(x, 0, CStr(groups.name))
            groups.hours = CInt(InputBox("input the number of hours of group no. " & CStr(x)))
            display(x, 1, CStr(groups.hours))
            groups.supporters = CInt(InputBox("number of supporters of group no. " & CStr(x)))
            display(x, 3, CStr(groups.supporters))
            groups.leader = CStr(InputBox("name of the person in charge of group no. " & CStr(x)))
            groups.status = CStr(InputBox("enter the level of group no." & CStr(x)))
            display(x, 2, CStr(groups.leader))

            total = total + groups.hours


        Next x
        display(x, 1, CStr(total))
        groups.average = total / groups.hours
        groups.ratio = groups.supporters / groups.average



    End Sub

    Private Function leveldetermine(ByVal level As Double) As Double

        Select Case level
                Case 1 To 10
            End Select
            Return MsgBox("not great")

            Select Case level
                Case 11 To 15
            End Select
            Return MsgBox("average")
            Select Case level
                Case 16 To 20
            End Select
            Return MsgBox("awesome")

    End Function

    Private Sub btn2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn2.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: [Select...Case Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For a start, your Select..Case..End Select block is structured incorrectly - it should also be a sub not a function because the code doesn't return a value.

```
Private Sub leveldetermine(ByVal level As Double)
    Select Case level
        Case 1 To 10
            MsgBox("not great")
        Case 11 To 15
            MsgBox("average")
        Case 16 To 20
            MsgBox("awesome")
    End Select
End Sub
```